# Java Comparator Interface NullsLast with anonymous inner class

Tags: java, sorting, generics, comparator

i've created a method that returns the raw html for a table in java based on the given entity (i use JPA). Now i'd like to be able to sort the table with the comparator interace. So i created an anonymous inner class of the comparator interface, to sort after attributes of the entities. This works fine, but my problem is now that i'm not able to sort NullsFirst or Nullslast. Everything i've tried doesn't works. Does anyone got an idea how to solve this?

This is the code:

```
if (!sortProperty.equals("") && sortProperty != null) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<T>() {
            public int compare(T e1, T e2) {
                Method sortGetter = null;
                try {
                    for (PropertyDescriptor pd : Introspector.getBeanInfo(entity).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
                        if (pd.getName().equals(sortProperty) && pd.getReadMethod() != null) {
                            sortGetter = pd.getReadMethod();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                        if (sortGetter.getReturnType().equals(String.class)) {
                            return sortGetter.invoke(e1).toString().compareTo(sortGetter.invoke(e2).toString());
                        } else if (sortGetter.getReturnType().equals(Integer.TYPE)) {
                                return (Integer) sortGetter.invoke(e1) - (Integer) sortGetter.invoke(e2);
                        } else if (sortGetter.getReturnType().equals(Date.class)) {
                                return ((Date) sortGetter.invoke(e1)).compareTo((Date) sortGetter.invoke(e2));
                        } else if (sortGetter.getReturnType().equals(Timestamp.class)) {
                                return ((Timestamp) sortGetter.invoke(e1)).compareTo((Timestamp) sortGetter.invoke(e2));
                        }
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: "Everything i've tried doesn't works. Does anyone got an idea how to solve this?" What have you tried? In what sense is it not "solved"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull out your `sortGetter.invoke(e1)` and `sortGetter.invoke(e2)` to variables (try/catch omitted for clarity):

```
Object o1 = sortGetter.invoke(e1);
Object o2 = sortGetter.invoke(e2);
```

Check if either is null, and if so, return:

```
if (o1 == null || o2 == null) {
  // This results in nulls last. Use != for nulls first.
  return Boolean.compare(o1 == null, o2 == null);
}
```

Now you can proceed with your `if (sortGetter.getReturnType().equals(String.class))`-type logic (you obviously don't need to invoke `sortGetter.invoke(e1)` and `sortGetter.invoke(e2)` again).